# javascript text similarity algorithm in percentage based on edit distance

Tags: javascript, text, similarity

I already know many edit-distance algorithm implementations in javascript, but I want to calculate the text similarity in percentage based on it. Does anyone know how to implement it?

Comment: and what how many edit-distance algorithm that you already know?

Comment: Yes someone knows how to implement it. Now go away and don't come back until you can ask a question that meets our minimum quality standards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to find the maximum possible distance between a string of length `n` and a string of length `m`. If for example this maximum distance is `n + m` then the percentage will be

```
100 - 100 * edit_distance(a, b) / (a.length + b.length)
```

If for example you use Levenshtein distance where each insert, replacement, deletion has cost `1` then this maximum possible distance is `max(n, m)` and so the percentage will be

```
100 - 100 * Levenshtein(a, b) / Math.max(a.length, b.length)
```